# Python filtering pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, aggregate-functions

Question: Output the ID of the user and a total number of actions they performed for tasks they completed(action_name column="CompleteTask"). If a user from this company(ClassPass) did not complete any tasks in the given period of time, you should still output their ID and the number 0 in the second column.

dataset:

[image]

expected result:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please add the data samples as text, not as pictures. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Both for input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your initial dataframe is named `df`, you can try this :

```
out = (df.groupby(['user_id'], as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda x: x[x['action_name'] == 'CompleteTask' ]['num_actions'].sum())
       .rename(columns={None: 'total_actions'})
      )
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]